# How do I change a machine name in DNS

Tags: dns, hostname

I'm trying to change my computer's name in DNS so that others on the same subnet can refer to it by its new name -

however, whatever changes I make in /etc/hosts and by using 'hostname' to use the **new_host_name** and shutting-down and starting, DNS *still gives me* the old host name.

1. I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 On...c
2. All my colleagues/partners are on the same 172.xx.30.xxx subnet

Q1. How do I make the change permanent in DNS?

Q2. Will this ensure that other computers can see my computer with the new *new_host_name*?

Thanks in advance for any guidance and answers,

Best,

Shailen

Comment: Where is the name being resolved?  If it is being resolved by the upstream nameserver, you'll have to have it changed there.

Comment: 0. I have a nameserver defined in /etc/resolv.conf: would it have to be changed there?
1. What exactly does 'having it changed there' entail? (I don't know enough to be able to tell my Windows IT guy, :-(, :-))

Comment: If you want other hosts on the network to automatically see your computer with the new host name (without modifying anything on their system), you will have to talk to your IT guy.  It is possibly the DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf that needs to be updated, but it could also be the DHCP server as well.  Windows can use NetBIOS names to resolve local machines, so that is another fish muddying the waters.  (bottom line, talk to your IT guy)

Comment: Thanks!
I talked to him,but he's soo 'booked up with other stuff' slow,    :-(, will just have to wait, and get the rest of the team to use IP's for now, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` to make it persistent between boots.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didn't fly, though, because there're MAC address foul ups across the DNS and DHCP servers ...